# Проблема при передаче AJAX запроса в Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, controller

Не понимаю, почему не получается передать запрос в контроллер средствами AJAX.

Цель: нужно изменить значение $article->public на 0 (по дефолту 1)

Делаю так

HTML:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />


<span id="timer" class="uk-badge">somedata</span><button type="button" title="Изменить" class="change">Изменить</button>
<input type="hidden" id="item_id" value="{{$item->id}}"/>
```

JS:

```
$('.change').click(function(){
span=$(this).parent(); 
item_id=$("#item_id").val();

$.ajax({
     url: '/change',
     method: 'PUT',
     data: {'id': item_id, 'public' : '0'},
     headers: {
          'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
     },
     success: function(res)
     {
          alert('ok');
      },
     error: function(msg){
          console.log(msg);
     }
     });
})
```

Route:

```
Route::put('change','HomeController@archivearticle');
```

Controller:

```
public function archivearticle(Request $request)
{

   $data = $request->all();
   dd($data);
}
```

В итоге консоль говорит это `PUT http://localhost:8000/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

Как это дело отладить. Или может есть другой вариант отправки PUT через AJAX?

Comment: положи в data {_method:"PUT"}

Answer (score 1):

Есть вероятность того, что Ваш сервер не обрабатывает запросы по PUT. Слышал что по дефолту этот метод закрыт, о чем и говорит ошибка 405.

Answer (score 0):

У меня была похожая проблема, get и post запросы проходили, а put и delete нет.
Я создал либу на php для запросов через curl и уже к ней выполнял через ajax вызов. Например, вот так выглядит put

```
class HttpRequestApi {
    function put($url, $parameters)
{
    $parameters = http_build_query($parameters);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $result = json_decode($result, true);

    return $result;
    }
}
```

Точно так же создаешь для get,post,delete. Ну и отдельный файл для запросов - в нем создаешь экземпляр класса HttpRequestApi и через него фигачишь запросы.